# how to put a picture in my header menu?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

im new in wordpress.

i want to put my logo in my menu but i dont find the header options in customize.

[header option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLM59.png)

[i dont have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWC7n.png)

i changed the logo by changing the picture in my folder using filezilla but its not working like i want to. i want to change the size of the logo to fit the menu header.

this problem is from the theme because when i was using another theme the header option exist but when i switch to my current theme the header option disappear.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your new theme doesn't support this option. Different themes can have different list of available options. So you have to edit css and/or html/php code of your new theme